# Why is there error in displaying an absolute positioned image?

Tags: css

Here is my css

```
.arrow_l, .arrow_r {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aeaeae;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 36px;
    opacity:.75;
}
.arrow_l {
    background: url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat 10px center,red;
    background-size: 116% auto;
}
 .arrow_r {
    background: url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat -15px center,red;
    background-size: 116% auto;
    margin-left:-36px;
```

}

[image]

The content is inside wrapper with css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

I am not getting it why the right arrow goes on bottom row and how can I fix it.

Comment: Post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rachit_rm/KgNbN/embedded/result/

Comment: If you paste the entire document in jsfiddle, you will have a document inside the body element of another document, so it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JsFiddle doesn't replicate the problem but from looking at your code and the information you have posted here I'd suggest you try a few things.

1. Firstly absolute positioning only works properly when the parent div's positioning is set to relative, you don't have this so try setting your parent div (i think it was called panel) to position:relative;
2. You have declared your arrows as absolute positioned items and then not actually positioned them... try something like

   ```
   .arrow_l {
       background: url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat 10px center,red;
       background-size: 116% auto;
       left:0px;
       top:25px;
   }
    .arrow_r {
       background: url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat -15px center,red;
       background-size: 116% auto;
       margin-left:-36px;
       right:0px;
       top:25px;
   }
   ```
3. Try using

   ```
   <div class="arrow_l"></div>
   ```

instead of

```
<span class="arrow_l"></span>
```

I don't understand why you've done this, is there a special reason?

Hope this helps :)